# link to item in edit mode

Tags: item

I need to build dynamic string that contain a link to SharePoint list item 
in edit mode.

I used the nintex forum:
http://connect.nintex.com/forums/thread/5536.aspx

What should the string contain?

Comment: Do you mind asking these Nintex questions on the nintex forum? After the [discussion we had](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/121/when-should-we-allow-questions-about-products-that-dont-belong-to-a-sharepoint-s), we decided that these types of questions are really off topic here. Since you already have some answers I'll leave your question open for a bit but I'd like to close it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

It's self explanitory in that article you referenced.  The build dynamic string operation Peter references shows you exactly what you need to do.  With that created, you can email that to a user, and when clicked, it will open the item in edit mode.

Comment: well... i try to do so and i receive the next error:           Source URL: msm/rd_cmd/sites001/Install_Release_Project/List/Install
The URL you are trying to visit is no longer valid. Please update your bookmark for this site.

You will redirected to the following URL in 10 seconds.

What on me to do?

Comment: Then remove the {Common:WebURL} portion and hard code everything like `http://myspdomain/sites/site/Lists/{Common:ListName}/Editform.aspx?ID={ItemProperty:ID}`

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to edit the item with an ID of 1 from the list called "Test", you'd use something like the following (substituting the appropriate site URL)

http://{SiteURL}/Lists/Test/EditForm.aspx?id={ID}

Comment: well... i try to do so and i receive the next error:      Source URL: msm/rd_cmd/sites001/Install_Release_Project/List/Install and Release/EditForm.aspx?ID=1
The URL you are trying to visit is no longer valid. Please update your bookmark for this site.

You will redirected to the following URL in 10 seconds.      What on me to do?

Comment: Please don't post the same comment on multiple answers.